# How to Join this two tables?

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

Hi there I have this tables in my DB.

```
REATE TABLE Titles (
    TitleID int NOT NULL ,
    ArtistID int NULL ,
    Title varchar (50) NULL ,
    StudioID int NULL ,
    UPC varchar (13) NULL ,
    Genre varchar (15) NULL 
);

Insert Into Titles Values(1,1,'Meet the Neurotics',1,'2727366627','alternative');
Insert Into Titles Values(3,15,'Smell the Glove',2,'1283772282','metal');
Insert Into Titles Values(4,10,'Time Flies',3,'1882344222','alternative');
Insert Into Titles Values(5,1,'Neurotic Sequel',1,'2828830202','alternative');
Insert Into Titles Values(6,5,'Sonatas',2,'3999320021','classical');
Insert Into Titles Values(7,2,'Louis at the Keys',3,'3838227111','jazz');

CREATE TABLE Studios (
    StudioID int PRIMARY KEY ,
    StudioName varchar (40) NULL ,
    Address varchar (60) NULL ,
    City varchar (25) NULL ,
    Region varchar (15) NULL ,
    PostalCode varchar (10) NULL ,
    Country varchar (20) NULL ,
    WebAddress varchar (40) NULL ,
    Contact varchar (50) NULL ,
    EMail varchar (40) NULL ,
    Phone varchar (16) NULL ,
    SalesID smallint NULL 
);
```

I am trying to list all pairs of titles and studio name for which both titles were recorded at the same studio. 
I have tried the following:

```
SELECT t1.Title, t2.Title, Studioname
FROM Titles t1, Titles t2, studios
WHERE t1.TitleID < t2.TitleID;
```

However, the above outputs a lot of duplicates and I'm not sure how to fix it.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by joining `Titles` to itself. But you need to describe the condition, which is that they share a common studio.

And you're on the right track by using `<` to make sure you don't get each pair appearing twice in reverse order. And of course the same TitleID shouldn't join to itself -- it has to be a different title.

```
. . .
FROM Titles t1 JOIN Titles t2 ON t1.StudioID = t2.StudioID
  AND t1.TitleID < t2.TitleID
. . .
```

Then based on either of these, since they both have the same StudioID, it doesn't matter which one you join to Studios. But you do have to make sure you match these Titles to their corresponding row from Studios.

```
. . .
JOIN Studios s ON t1.StudioID = s.StudioID
```